# Implementing AdMob conflicts with Support AppCompat V7 28.0.0

Tags: android, admob, build.gradle

**Implementing Google AdMOb 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0' conflicts whit "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0" in Android Studio Gradle.**

The implementation of 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0', its one of the first and basic dependencies that have in my project and its was working perfect until now that I add the AdMob dependency.

The following warning message apears under 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' after syncing the Gradle:

*All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixig versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found version 28.0.0, 26.1.0*

I have found that inserting the following code in the android section of the gradle...

```
android {
....
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "28.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
....
```

... the problem is solve when syncing, but i dont think this is the best solution. Any ideas?

Image Reference guide:
(A) with out AdMob dependency, syncing OK
(B) with AdMob, sync shows the version conflict
(C) with the configuration code, no error.
[image]

Comment: what about `play-services-ads:17.1.3` ?

Comment: I just try: Same result